# Unable to Create new Maintenance plan in SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms, installation, maintenance-plans

Hi I have reinstalled SQL Server 2016 in my database server last day.
I am able to connect to SQL Instance(SQL-02) using the SSMS 2017 i had earlier in the same server before reinstall.

But when i try to create the maintenance plans,i get the below error.

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8357986F-76E9-4E0A-A780-FB0541E91ECC} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)
```

I have done enough research on this and learned from several posts from web that i have to run the below command

```
REGSVR32.EXE dts.dll
```

and then disconnect from SSMS and reconnect.
For most of the people ,this solved the issue and for me i still the issue.

I have my sql server in d: drive and i ran the above command as administrator in the below location.

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn
```

I get the message that the .dll is loaded successfuly.
But when i try to create a new maintenance plan i still get the same error.

I didn't find any other solution for this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional Info:

I have another database sever in the same domain.
I can connect the same instance(SQL-02) in that server's SSMS 2017 and can create new maintenance plan for the instance.
I am using the same version of SSMS in both servers.

Comment: There were a lot of bugs in v17 with regards to maintenance plans. The odds of you getting much support from MS or anyone here for an out of date version are slim - just upgrade to the latest version and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: And, FWIW, you can have SSMS 17 ad SSMS 18 side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for this error as it just occurred on my instance as well. Although it wasn't identical, I wanted to put this out there if anyone else runs into the same problem when searching.

- Server 2019
- SQL Server Standard 2017 (14.0.2027.2)
- SSMS 2018 (v.18.5.1)

Went to create a new maintenance plan (the first one on this server and named instance) and received a very similar error out of the gate: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib) Invalid Class String.

I checked all components, etc and my fix was to install SSMS 2017 and use it rather than SSMS 2018. Works just fine now.